# BufferedReader.readLine is not working

Tags: java

My program kind of gets stuck after the readLine call, the if statements don't work. What am i doing wrong? #java-first-timer

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class nums {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));               
        System.out.println("Number Mania!!!");
        System.out.println("Pick your favourite number from 1 to 5");
        String favNum = br.readLine();
        if (favNum=="3"){
            System.out.println("Your favourite number is three!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("hi!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another day, another `==` String comparison... This question may interest you: [how do I compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Then this will be also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698260/what-makes-reference-comparison-work-for-some-strings-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `favNum.equals("3")` instead of `favNum == "3"`.  You should almost never use `==` to compare objects; use `.equals` instead.  (There are a few rare exceptions, but you won't need to worry about them until you learn a fair bit more Java.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know what makes it hang when using "=="? I'd prefer if it crashed instead, so at least I knew something was wrong.

Comment: It shouldn't hang outright; it should have just printed "hi!" and exited.

Answer (score 2):

Use `favNum.equals("3")` to compare Strings... actually, there is very few occasions that you should use `==` comparator for String comparison.

As the second suggestion, you should consider start using the `java.util.Scanner` class. Your code could be like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nums {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scann = new Scanner(System.in);               
        System.out.println("Number Mania!!!");
        System.out.println("Pick your favourite number from 1 to 5");
        int favNum = scann.nextInt();
        if (favNum == 3){
            System.out.println("Your favourite number is three!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("hi!");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: Do you know what makes it hang when using "=="? I'd prefer if it crashed instead, so at least I knew something was wrong

Comment: @JoseSwagKid `==` tests for reference equality while `.equals()` tests for value equality. You should look at links given by Pshemo