# If I have 2 reference types, with the same value, does that mean only 1 object in memory

Tags: java, pointers

I'm new to Java and have read a conflicting statement to what I believe. Please consider the following code.

```
String str1 = "dave";
String str2 = "dave";
```

Both str1 and str2, although unique variables, reference the exact same value. So, how many unique objects are created in memory? 1 or 2 and can some one explain why?

Comment: What about trying? Open Java, and print their references after you run that code...

Comment: Take a look at [What makes reference comparison (==) work for some strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698260/what-makes-reference-comparison-work-for-some-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example they reference to the same object, because the strings are [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

In general, usage of **new** creates new objects, thus using:

```
String str1 = new String("dave");
String str2 = new String("dave");
```

would create two different objects in the heap.

Comment: +1: good general note: using `new` **always** creates a new object.

Answer (score 10):

It's not so complicated. Except if you're talking about Strings ;-)

First, let's ignore Strings and assume this simple type:

```
public class ValueHolder {
  private final int value;

  public ValueHolder(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

If you have two lines like this:

```
ValueHolder vh1 = new ValueHolder(1);
ValueHolder vh2 = new ValueHolder(1);
```

then you'll have created exactly 2 objects on the heap. Even though they behave exactly the same and have the exact same values stored in them (and can't be modified), you will have two objects.

So `vh1 == vh2` will return `false`!

The same is true for `String` objects: two `String` objects with the same value *can* exist.

**However**, there is one specific thing about `String`: if you use a `String` literal<sup>(*)</sup> in your code, Java will try to re-use any earlier occurance of this (via a process called [interning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29)).

So in your example code `str1` and `str2` **will point to the same object**.

<sup>(*)</sup> or more precisely: a [compile-time constant expression of type `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Comment: What a very well explained answer, with a very useful link. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You have one unique `Object` & 2 references pointing to the same object. This is as a result of `String` pooling (or interning). Given that both `String` literals have identical content, the only way to ensure that 2 *separate* `Objects` could be created would be to to explicitly invoke one of the `String` constructors.

Comment: Does this mean though, if I changed str1, the value of str2 would also change since their pointing at the same location?

Comment: You can't _change_ `str1` (unless by reflection) as `Strings` are immutable. You can change the reference to point to a different `String` though. In this case the value of the other reference is not affected.

Comment: so later if I do str1 = "dave2", it actually make a new string object of "dave2" and make str1 reference to the object of "dave2"?

Comment: @cwhsu: exactly! (although "make a new string object" *could be replaced by* "take the correct string object out of the interned string pool", if `"dave2"` was already needed somewhere before).

Comment: @cwhsu It will only create a new `String` of a matching one does not already exist on the pool.

Comment: So, in Java, a string is both a reference type and immutable?

Comment: To clarify, String is the reference `Object` data type whose instances are immutable (reflection aside). Also, the only way to guarantee that the a new `String` `Object` is actually created is to explicitly invoke one of the String constructors.

Answer (score 0):

it depends. if you write a little test program, then there's a very good chance that they will contain the same reference, because java is trying to do you a favor by saving memory and reusing references. if str2 came from user input, then it would likely be two different references. a good way to test is to use == in a comparison. if the two are ==, then they are referencing the same memory location. if they are not, then they are two different references. this throws off a lot of beginning programmers because when they first start writing code, they use ==, see that it works, then down the road can't figure out why their comparisons aren't working.

i can't explain specifically when java does reuse references "behind the scenes" but it's related to how and when the values are created

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a short-hand version of this

```
String str1 = new String("dave");
String str2 = new String("dave");
```

So str1 and str2 are different objects and may be modified separately as such

"dave", the original string, exists once only in memory, with another reference.