# String literal vs String object not behaving as I though it would?

Tags: java, eclipse

EDIT?:

I'm writing some code to get a better understanding of the String class, specifically with the == and .equals comparators.

My program is relatively simple.  I've declared 2 String literals and 1 String object, all with the same value "banana".

I understand that == is essentially testing the physical memory reference and .equals is actually checking the value contained.

So why then is my 3rd conditional statement coming true if I declared strtest4 as a new object?  All the others make sense.

```
private static String str;   
private static String strtest;  
private static String strtest4 = new String();   


public static void main(String[] args) { 

    str = "banana";
    strtest = "banana";
    strtest4 = "banana";

    if (str == strtest) System.out.println("str and strtest point to same location in memory");
    if (str.equals(strtest)) System.out.println("str and strtest have the same value contained");

    if (str == strtest4) System.out.println("\nstr and strtest4 point to same location in memory");
    if (str.equals(strtest4)) System.out.println("str and strtest4 have the same value contained");     

}
```

I receive the following output when I run the program:

> str and strtest point to same location in memory
>
> str and strtest have the same value contained
>
> str and strtest4 point to same location in memory
>
> str and strtest4 have the same value contained

Comment: Additional answer that may provide more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9698305/1424875

Comment: Because you're not creating a new instance with `new String()` but it's using the cached constant string "banana", therefore both `str` and `strtest4` point to the same object.

Comment: @dabadaba  Thanks!  I guess my next question would be,  how do you create a completely separate new instance in this case?

Comment: I did use 'new'.  What are you talking about

Comment: `strtest4 = "banana";` and `str = "banana";`... you didn't use `new`

Comment: @dabadaba   ah ok, I see what you're talking about.  I thought that issue was taking care of when I initially declared strtest4 with "private static String strtest4 = new String(); " ??

Comment: it doesn't matter how you declared those objects initially, when assigning another value you're changing the reference they're pointing to. Try doing `new String("banana") == new String("banana")` and you'll see that's `false`. But the way you're doing it is `true` because it's like if you were doing `"banana" == "banana"` which is obviously the same object.

Comment: @dabadaba   ahh, ok.  It's because I declared "strtest4" as a literal within my main method, despite creating it as a new object.  gotcha, thanks!

Comment: Don't confuse variables, reference values and objects.