# Using == instead of equals in String comparison not getting caught by Sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I have below code :

```
String s1 = "a";
    String s2 = "a";
    if (s1 == s2) {
        System.out.println("string not equal");
    }
```

When I analyze this code using SonarLint it doesnt get caught by it.
I expect this should get caught by below Rule

> squid:S1698-"==" and "!=" should not be used when "equals" is overridden

I have checked this both in standalone as well as in connected mode with Sonar Qube 7.0.
Does anybody has any idea about this why sonar is behaving like this?

---------------Edit------------------

Same is also happening for :

```
Integer x= 500;
Integer y= 500;
if (x==y){
            System.out.println("not equal");
        }
```

Comment: It possibly isn't showing the warning because they're `String` literals. if you change one of them to `new String("a");` does it show the warning?

Comment: actually this is correct behavior  because you are using string literals and they are interned by default `intern()` and added to constant pool. so in this case == will be correct. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698260/what-makes-reference-comparison-work-for-some-strings-in-java

Comment: @GBlodgett .If I change it to new String("a").Sonar gives me error -Constructors should not be used to instantiate "String" but still doesnt give the equals error

Comment: @Nonika -Shouldnt sonar rule squid:S1698 apply in this case ?

Comment: @Rips I have just tested the **Noncompliant Code Sample** part and the output is `they're both 'blue',
they're both 'blue',
they're the same object`. so it prints all the lines. there are same string objects under the hood

Comment: @Nonika sonarkube isn't supposed to tell you if your code is correct or not. It's supposed to prevent using bad practices like comparing objects with equals(). The fact that, in this very specific case, == would lead to a correct result is irrelevant. It's still bad practice to use == to compare strings. Because, fore example, if one of the strings isn't a literal anymore in the next edition of the code, then the test will fail.

Comment: @Rips have you checked the obvious, i.e. is the rule enabled?

Comment: @JBNizet .Yes rule is enabled.Also I would have expected SonarLint standalone plugin to also catch such basic issue when even IntelliJ's inspector also reports it as an issue

Comment: Yes of course this is bad practice and one shouldn't ever use == to compare strings by value.